# Rails custom validate breaks my tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I have the following cart model which contains many line items. It contains only one method which adds a new line item and increment its quantity.

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
  validate :cart_total_price_cannot_be_greater_than_500

  def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)

    # Updates quantity or add a new line item
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity += 1
    else
      current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
              current_item.quantity = 1
      product = Product.find(product_id)
      current_item.product_price = product.price
    end

    current_item
  end

  def cart_total_price
    line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.product_price * item.quantity }
  end

  def cart_total_price_cannot_be_greater_than_500
    if cart_total_price > 500 
      errors.add(:base, "has a too high price") 
    end
  end
end
```

The line item model is the following:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart

  def total_price
    product.price * quantity
  end
end
```

The following test was working correctly:

```
require 'test_helper'

class CartTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :products

  test "add duplicated products to cart" do
    cart = Cart.create

    # :ruby is a product
    cart.add_product(products(:ruby).id).save
    cart.add_product(products(:ruby).id).save

    assert_equal 1, cart.line_items.size
    assert_equal 2, cart.line_items.first.quantity
  end
end
```

All went well until I added the third line `validate :cart_total_price_cannot_be_greater_than_500`. This is now breaking my tests and i get the following error from `rake test`:

```
Finished tests in 0.294143s, 23.7979 tests/s, 84.9927 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
test_add_duplicated_products_to_cart(CartTest) [/home/luca/Documents/Sites/depot/test/unit/cart_test.rb:14]:
<2> expected but was
<1>.
```

What I am doing wrong? If I comment out the validate method, tests will pass correctly.

P.S. my second question is: why if I don't add the "to_a" method before calling sum on the cart_total_price method it does not work?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** about the second matter, isn't the to_a method querying the database without performing the sum? I would like to perform the calculation on the db rather than server-side. I am learning Rails from .NET and in LINQ I could have used:

```
int sum = dbContext.LineItems.Where(l => l.CartId == cartId).Sum(l => l.Quantity * l.ProductPrice)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little intricate. First consider the no validation case.

You're calling `line_items.find_by_product_id` and `line_items.build`. None of this actually causes the line_items association to be loaded, so when in the last line of your test you ask for `cart.line_items.first` the line item is loaded fresh from the db, with quantity == 2.

In the second case your validation (which runs when `Cart.create` is called) forces rails to try and load the association from the db (empty at this point). When you build your line_item, this built object gets added to the cache of the loaded association (quantity == 1)

You then add the product a second time. `line_items.find_by_product_id` fetches the product from the db. Since activerecord has no identity map, this is actually a separate ruby object from the line item held in the cache (albeit one that refers to the same database object). That (now stale) object still has quantity == 1, although the row in the database has a quantity of 2.

When you ask for `cart.line_items.first` rails sees that it has already got that association loaded and so gives you back the cached line item object from the first call to add_product, which has the stale quantity value. Thus your assertion fails.

You could make your spec pass by calling `cart.reload` after you've added the products.

To answer to your second question it's because the `to_a` results in Array#sum being called whereas without it rails things you want to do an SQL sum over the line items which requires a different set of arguments.

Comment: Thank you! I could never had figured on my own. About the second question, isn't the to_a method querying the database for all the line items? I edited the question to explain better.

Comment: It is indeed. You're fetching all the items and then using array's sum method (which you can use on an array of anything). line_items.sum(:price) does a database side sum

Comment: Can't I provide a block to sum? I tried `line_items.sum { |item| item.product_price * item.quantity }` but it didn't work.

Comment: Not the SQL version - it doesn't know how to turn that into SQL.